# Geo maps setup in GoodData

Tags: gooddata

Can anyone help me with preparing data for the new feature Geo Maps. I want to show the below data on geo maps.

Country Name    Sales
Russia          1244
Canada          3553
Germany         5345
Australia   2456
France          2566
United Kingdom  6743
India           3677
United States   5633

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the setup is quite easy and you can find out more information here:

https://developer.gooddata.com/article/setting-up-data-for-geo-charts

Basically it is about setting up the correct date type for columns that represents geo-information.

JT

Comment: 404 on link above